# Get token for OAuth2 protected API in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

When I use a browser I use this endpoint to authorize:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&scope=email+offline_access+openid+profile&state=&prompt=select_account

then I log in to my Microsoft account, and it redirects me to my application.

How I can log in to get a token from PowerShell? I need it for test automation. I found something like this (https://github.com/shawntabrizi/Microsoft-Authentication-with-PowerShell-and-MSAL/tree/master/Authorization%20Code%20Grant%20Flow) but I'm not sure if it is a good solution for my case.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT:

I don't know how to automate this step:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your test to call the API as an app, you can use client credentials flow.

If on the other hand you want to call the API on behalf of a user, you might need to use resource owner password credentials grant flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Note that the user should usually be a local account in that AAD tenant (no external user/Microsoft account/on-prem AD account) with no MFA.
Take this into account and store the user credentials securely.
And do use a test AAD tenant for this so the credentials don't have access to any production environments.

Comment: Hm, how these two approaches are different in my case? I want to test API endpoints and I need a valid token, doesn't matter how I will get it. Or should it matter to me? Client credentials flow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) is simpler than resource owner password credentials right?

Comment: Well it matters from your API's perspective. Do you expect a client app to call the API on behalf of a user (i.e. there is user info in the access token)? Client credentials flow is for service to service scenarios where an app calls an API with application permissions instead of delegated permissions.

Answer (score -1):

We can use MSAL library in PowerShell .

[MSAL.PS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS/4.16.0.3) module's `Get-MSALToken` function which prompted  to return a valid token that you could use.

**Example:-**
To Force interactive authentication to get AccessToken (with MS Graph permissions User.Read) and IdToken for specific Azure AD tenant and UPN using client id from application  registration (public client).

```
 PS C:\>Get-MsalToken -ClientId '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -TenantId '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -Interactive -Scope 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read'
    -LoginHint user@domain.com
```

Comment: Where I can find examples for MSAL for different OAuth2 flows?

Comment: Hi @TomaszKaniewski, Just updated my answer with an example. Please let me know if you still need any help.

Comment: Ok, but where I can put password for my user@domain.com?

Comment: When we run the command it will popup for the login  to enter username and password.

Comment: I need it for test automation in CD pipelines. I need to aquire authorization code without any manuał interaction, whole process have to be automated.

Comment: If you want to automate without username and password manual entry then use client credential flow instead of auth ccode flow